# Derived classes not using all pure virtual methods from the base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a similar situation:

```
class Question{
virtual double getPoints(double userAnswer) const = 0;
virtual double getPoints(const std::string & userAnswer) const = 0;
.
.
};

class QText : public Question{
double getPoints(const std::string & userAnswer) const;
.
.
};

class QNumeric : public Question{
double getPoints(double userAnswer) const;
.
.
};
```

And I need to be able to do something like this this:

```
std::vector<Question*> quiz;
quiz.push_back(new QText(..));
quiz.push_back(new QNumeric(..));
quiz[0]->getPoints(..);
quiz[1]->getPoints(..);
```

I understand that if I don't implement a pure virtual function in a derived class, the class will be abstact and I won't be able to create an instance of that class. Is there a way to do what I want or should I just rethink the whole design?

Comment: What does `getPoints` do?  If we knew we could help you make one that works for both.

Comment: If you try to replace `..` with an actual value, you will see the problem. Try it, then swap `[0]` and `[1]` and see if the proposed usage still makes sense.

Comment: Your interface says that derived classes must implement *all* of those methods, not *one of* those methods, so I would not use that design

Comment: The problem here is that the code provides two distinct pure virtual functions. Having one derived type implement one of them and a different derived type implement the other one leaves you with a problem: how do you determine which one you can call when you have only a pointer to the base type? This is a fundamental type error.

Comment: May be there is really no common ancestor to those two concrete types.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. My compiler wont swallow things like `..` without complaining alot

Comment: @user463035818, do not be a nitpicker. It is quite clear what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @NathanOliver `getPoints()` is supposed to return the amount of points an user gets for answering the question with `userAnswer`

Comment: @SergeyA hm, sorry I really dont get it, maybe I was staring at code for too long already today, but I am a nitpicker anyhow :P

Comment: @user463035818 The "working" example would be too long so I figured it might be better to post the question like this instead.

Comment: @skluzada So, whatever you pass to `getPoints` will be compared to an answer and result is returned?  If that is the case then can't you just use a string for all of it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I guess that's the only way to do what I want - pass string and then parse the answer in the function.

Comment: If a derived class does not need functions provided by a base class (virtual or otherwise), it's possible deriving from that base is the wrong design decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you are asking, simply don't make your virtual methods be abstract.  Give them default implementations in the base class, eg:

```
class Question
{
    virtual double getPoints(double userAnswer) const;
    virtual double getPoints(const std::string & userAnswer) const;
    ...
};

double Question::getPoints(double userAnswer) const
{
    return getPoints(std::to_string(userAnswer));
}

double Question::getPoints(const std::string & userAnswer) const
{
    std::istringstream iss(userAnswer);
    double dblAnswer;
    return (iss >> dblAnswer) ? getPoints(dblAnswer) : 0.0;
}
```

Then descendants can override only the virtual methods they are interested in, as long as they override at least one of them, and the overrides don't call back to the base class methods.  Otherwise you end up in a recursive loop.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I decided to create a `struct UserAnswer` that can store `std::string`, `double` and other types as well, so that the `getPoints` functions can all have the same parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should rethink the design.  In its current state, this design breaks the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), since `QText` would need to implement `getPoints(double userAnswer)`, which it doesn't require, and `QNumeric` would need to implement `getPoints(const std::string& userAnswer)`, which it doesn't require.

Comment: While this statement is correct, it is not an answer to OP's question. This should be a comment.

Comment: I would love to.... but I only have 46 rep.

Comment: But posts like that **do not** help you to gain rep.

Comment: And to be fair, the question is "should I just rethink the whole design", which I did answer.

Comment: Perhaps make that clearer?  "Yes.  You should rethink the whole design."

Comment: Is that more acceptable?